# CanvasCaptureMediaStream / MediaRecorder Frame Synchronization

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

When using [CanvasCaptureMediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasCaptureMediaStream) and MediaRecorder, is there a way to get an event on each frame?

What I need is not unlike [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), but I need it for the CanvasCaptureMediaStream (and/or the MediaRecorder) and not the window.  The MediaRecorder could be running at a different frame rate than the window (possibly at a not regularly divisible rate, such as 25 FPS vs 60 FPS), so I want to update the canvas at its frame rate rather than the window's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>**This example currently only fully works on FireFox**, since chrome simply stops the canvas stream when the tab is blurred... <sub>(probably related to [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=653548#c1), but well, my timer seems to be working but not the recording...)</sub></s>

**[Edit]**: it actually now works only in chrome, since they have fixed [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=653548#c1), but not anymore in FF because of [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1344524) (caused by e10s).

---

There doesn't seem to be any event on MediaStream letting you know when a frame has been rendered to it, neither on the MediaRecorder.

Even the `currentTime` property of the MediaStream (currently only available in FF) doesn't seem to be changing accordingly with the fps argument passed in the `captureStream()` method.

But what you seem to want is a reliable timer, that won't loose its frequency when i.e the current tab is not focused (which happens for rAF).
Fortunately, the WebAudio API does also have an [high precision timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/currentTime), based on hardware clock, rather than on screen refresh rate.

So we can come with an alternative timed loop, able to keep its frequency even when the tab is blurred.

```js
/*
 An alternative timing loop, based on AudioContext's clock

 @arg callback : a callback function 
  with the audioContext's currentTime passed as unique argument
 @arg frequency : float in ms;
 @returns : a stop function
 
*/
function audioTimerLoop(callback, frequency) {

  // AudioContext time parameters are in seconds
  var freq = frequency / 1000;

  var aCtx = new AudioContext();
  // Chrome needs our oscillator node to be attached to the destination
  // So we create a silent Gain Node
  var silence = aCtx.createGain();
  silence.gain.value = 0;
  silence.connect(aCtx.destination);

  onOSCend();

  var stopped = false;
  function onOSCend() {
    osc = aCtx.createOscillator();
    osc.onended = onOSCend;
    osc.connect(silence);
    osc.start(0);
    osc.stop(aCtx.currentTime + freq);
    callback(aCtx.currentTime);
    if (stopped) {
      osc.onended = function() {
        return;
      };
    }
  };
  // return a function to stop our loop
  return function() {
    stopped = true;
  };
}


function start() {

  // start our loop @25fps
  var stopAnim = audioTimerLoop(anim, 1000 / 25);
  // maximum stream rate set as 25 fps
  cStream = canvas.captureStream(25);

  let chunks = [];
  var recorder = new MediaRecorder(cStream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = e => chunks.push(e.data);
  recorder.onstop = e => {
    // we can stop our loop
    stopAnim();
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(chunks));
    var v = document.createElement('video');
    v.src = url;
    v.controls = true;
    document.body.appendChild(v);
  }
  recorder.start();
  // stops the recorder in 20s, try to change tab during this time
  setTimeout(function() {
    recorder.stop();
  }, 20000)
}


// make something move on the canvas
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0;
function anim() {
  x = (x + 2) % (canvas.width + 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'ivory';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(x - 50, 20, 50, 50)
};

btn.onclick = start;
```

```html
<button id="btn">begin</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Nota Bene** :
In this example, I set the frequency to 25fps, but we can set it to 60fps and it seems to work correctly even on my old notebook, at least with such a simple animation.

Comment: Interesting creative solution.  I'll experiment with it.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution no longer works in current builds of chrome, I would suggest this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-timers to do any sort of background rendering/timing.

Comment: @JacobGreenway the timer does work here. What got broken is the canvas to mediastream step.