# Laravel php timelapse an UploadedFile video element, without saving it as a file

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, frame-rate, timelapse

I want to be able to change the frame rate of a video from **0.05fps** to **3fps**.
I receive the video as an `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` element, with **mp4** format, how do I speed up its frame rate before sending it via email?
The video is 25 minutes long, it should become 25 seconds long after changing the frame rate.
Is there a way to change the fps without saving the element as a File?
I was planning to use the ffmpeg repository [here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) but it requires me to save both the initial file, and the second file after changing the fps.
This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Server\Mail;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

class TimeLapse extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public UploadedFile $video;

    public bool $is_timelapsed;

    public string $format;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        UploadedFile $video, 
        bool $is_timelapsed, 
        string $format
    ){
        $this->video = $video;
        $this->is_timelapsed = $is_timelapsed;
        $this->format = $format;
    }

    private function timelapse(){
        // here I want to change $video element's fps from 0.05 to 3
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        if ( !$is_timelapsed ) { timelapse(); }

        $this->subject('message')
                    ->text('emails.timelapse');

        $this->attach($this->video, [
            'as' => 'sample'.$format,
            'mime' => 'video/'.$format,
        ]);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know PHP, but you need to either use [the `setpts` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) or force change the input framerate (`-r 3 -i ...`). The latter is a brute-force approach, and it may not always work.

Comment: @kesh Thanks, but is it possible for me to do that without having to save the file on my server?

Comment: Yes. FFmpeg can modify the parameter on the fly as you stream. (That being said, you may need to re-encode on the fly to achieve this, which may not be what you'd like to do, but give it a try first.)

Comment: @kesh I am recording the video using MediaRecorder API on javascript. [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412855/create-a-timelapse-video-using-mediarecorder-api-and-ffmpeg?noredirect=1#comment129698456_73412855). At what point, and how should I call ffmpeg to modify the parameter?

Comment: You seem to be telling 2 different stories ("without having to save the file on my server" vs. "recording the video")... In any case, all I can say is "it 100% depends on your app design/logic." All, I can tell you from ffmpeg perspective is that it can change the rate when it transcodes (again, probably not if you're just stream copying)

Comment: I found a solution for javascript MediaRecorder API [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412855/create-a-timelapse-video-using-mediarecorder-api-and-ffmpeg?noredirect=1#comment129698456_73412855) (so before sending the video to the server side), but it does not exactly answer this question, so I will be leaving it open.