# Is there a way to perform video rendering on a worker thread?

Tags: javascript, canvas, web-worker, media-source, mediastream

I have video coming from a MediaStream object. My javascript main thread does other heavy compute, so if I render the video on main thread, it causes a lot of stutter. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747615/10093191 to render video frames on an OffscreenCanvas but the logic here is still driven by grabFrame()/postMessage() calls from the main thread.

Is there a way I can avoid the main thread involvement during rendering?

Comment: ...Not yet no...  There is this early proposal, but we'll have to wait. https://discourse.wicg.io/t/proposal-offscreenvideo/3952

Comment: Closing as a dupe of the one you pointed to, since a solution to your question would still apply there.