# Is there any explanation why when tab is hidden, Canvas stops receive frames from OffscreenCanvas drawImage in worker thread?

Tags: javascript, canvas, worker, mediarecorder, offscreen-canvas

I have a video merger that gets different `MediaStreamTrack` from `navigator.mediaDevices`, Camera, and Display and sends them to a worker via `MediaStreamTrackProcessor.reader` which reads each stream frame by frame and draws into an `OffscreenCanvas`. So, the `Canvas` inside the main thread which is synced to that `OffscreenCanvas` would work just fine and renders each frame drawn into `OffscreenCanvas`, Until the tab gets blurred and the main thread goes hidden (background tab). In that case, the main canvas stops rendering any frame (with OffscreenCanvas working well on other side) which would be impossible to record its captured stream with `MediaRecorder`.

I already have the solution to get `offscreen.transferToImageBitmap()` and post it back to the main thread and then render it to the main canvas via `canvasContext.transferFromImageBitmap()`. And it is working all good. But it gets tricky on some gaming laptops and PCs with 2 or more GPUs installed and causes an fps drop from `60fps` to something around `10fps`. That would not be ideal for my application.

I have been searching for an answer for so many days now and it started to bother me why it's acting like that.

Any tips/answers leading to fix this issue and making that background tab effect go away would be much appreciated <3

Here is a sample extracted from my code, in charge of merging tracks in a worker thread:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();

const coWorker = () => {
    let offscreen;
    let ctx;
    let streams = new Map();
    let started = false;
    let framesCount = 0;
    let lastFramesCount = 0;
    let fpsReport = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
        console.log('worker_fps', fpsReport)
        fpsReport = framesCount - lastFramesCount;
        lastFramesCount = framesCount;
    }, 1000);

    const renderFrames = () => {
        streams.forEach(async (reader) => {
            const {value} = await reader.read();
            ctx.drawImage(value, 0,0, 1280, 720);
            value.close();
            framesCount += 1;
            renderFrames();
        });
    };

    self.onmessage = event => {
        const {type, id, readable} = event.data;
        switch (type) {
            case 'Canvas': {
                offscreen = event.data.offscreen;
                ctx = offscreen.getContext('2d');
                break;
            }
            case 'AddStream': {
                streams.set(id, readable.getReader());
                if (!started) {
                    started = true;
                    renderFrames();
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                self.postMessage(`Error: ${event.data.msg}`, []);
        }
    };

}

const worker = new Worker(
    window.URL.createObjectURL(
        new Blob(["(" + coWorker.toString() + ")()"], {type: "text/javascript"})
    )
);

worker.postMessage({type: 'Canvas', offscreen}, [offscreen]);

// Starts here by getting screen-share video track

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: {frameRate: 60}}).then((stream) => {
    const videoTrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    if (videoTrack) {
        const processor = new MediaStreamTrackProcessor({track: videoTrack});
        worker.postMessage({type: 'AddStream', id: stream.id, readable: processor.readable,}, [processor.readable]);
    }
});

// recorder
const chunks = [];
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvas.captureStream(30), {mimeType: 'video/webm;'});
recorder.start();
const recorderInterval = setInterval(() => {
    recorder.requestData();
}, 1000)
recorder.ondataavailable = event => {
    const currentTarget = event.currentTarget;
    const blob = new Blob([event.data]);
    console.log('MediaRecorded:', currentTarget.state, event.data.size, currentTarget.mimeType, {
        data: event.data,
        blob,
    });
    if (event.data.size > 0) chunks.push(blob);
    if (chunks.length > 20 && recorder.state === 'recording') {
        recorder.stop();
        clearInterval(recorderInterval);
    }
};
recorder.onstop = () => {
    const data = new Blob(chunks, {type: this.type});
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.webm';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 100);
};
```

When you run it and share your screen, until you stay on the tab it will work fine and record canvas stream. When you go to another tab or window, it will start recording 0 bytes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The *OffscreenCanvas* API has been modeled so that it commits new frames to its placeholder `<canvas>` in `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks.
`requestAnimationFrame` has been modeled so that it runs only when new data can be painted to the monitor. When your tab is blurred, no new data can be painted to the monitor, so `requestAnimationFrame` callbacks won't fire. This means that your `OffscreenCanvas`'s new drawings won't be committed to its placeholder `<canvas>`, and its captured `MediaStream` won't receive new data that your `MediaRecorder` will be able to record.

This is actually a design flaw. There used to be a `.commit()` method on the `OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D` interface, but it's been removed from implementations. Now implementations have to have some hooks that check when a `<canvas>` stream is being recorded and to not throttle `requestAnimationFrame` in that case. [Firefox only recently](https://bugzil.la/1344524) did that for foreground `requestAnimationFrame` (they don't expose the `Worker`'s one yet), and [Chrome team is actively working](https://crbug.com/1343635) on fixing it on their `Worker`'s `requestAnimationFrame`.
So the best for you might unfortunately be to wait, though you may already have your case fixed in the latest Chrome Canary.

Comment: That is what I figured so much :) I just wanted to be sure I don't miss anything that might help. Thank you.

Comment: @Spleen, no there isn't much you can do to workaround that for now. The actual best you could do would be to move your canvas back to the main thread, where your drawings would be passed correctly to the compositor even when rAF is throttled. (You'd still need an alternate timer though, either setTimeout in a Worker, either a WebAudioAPI based one as exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687010/canvascapturemediastream-mediarecorder-frame-synchronization/40691112#40691112)).

Comment: I have no problem with looping over stream frames and there is no need for setTimeout, Interval, or even RAF. I just use while and it works just fine. the only problem is on sync OffscreenCanvas with the main Canvas on background tab. I used a `bitmaprenderer` on main canvas and sent bitmaps from worker to update canvas and it works for now, but with a low fps on windows.